# Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HTMLElement'

Tags: typescript

```js
const labelEl: HTMLElement = document.createElement('label')
const isElOfNeededType = (el: HTMLElement): boolean =>
    ["INPUT", "TEXTAREA"].includes(el.tagName);

let result

if (isElOfNeededType(labelEl.nextElementSibling)) {
    result = true
}
```

Here's my playground: [link](https://typescript-play.js.org/?target=99#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgQwEYFM4FE4C4YAkAqAsgDKYoC2KYsAvDACYjACul1AdMAE4oJQpk2UABQByRKjiiAlAChQkWAEsImAPIAzAHIoU9PfgCeABxQw6wtDgIlBVKNJxIQIOLzDmAfLJi+YAbQAiAEktAAUAVXxAgBoYQPx0AA18AEEAJXRUwIBddiUwYDhmfQhLOHYoBABzLQRKaQBuWVk3WB4IZjgoFqUNGGEVdW1dfXojU2EJNEx2MBQADyg7agBlJSQ4AurpaRgAbx8-Dq7aGCguZhRZAF8gA)

1. Why am I getting this error on `labelEl.nextElementSibling`?

   > Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HTMLElement'

Doesn't `HTMLElement` extend `Element`?

*2. (not really important, but would be glad if explained)* Why does TS playground complains about `[ ].includes` whereas I've set `Config -> Target = esnext` ?

Comment: Your ts playground link doesn't work

Comment: Fixed the link; don't know how permanent it is

Answer (score 2):

`labelEl.nextElementSibling` is of type `Element`. See the [definition](http://definitelytyped.org/docs/flipsnap--flipsnap/interfaces/htmlelement.html#nextelementsibling) in Definitely Typed. So your code is trying to pass an `Element` where an `HTMLElement` is required.

As you say, `HTMLElement` extends `Element`, but this does mean you can pass an `Element` in place of an `HTMLElement`, because the `Element` may not have properties that an `HTMLElement` does. You could however pass an `HTMLElement` where an `Element` is expected, because an `HTMLElement` will have all the properties of an `Element`.

Seeing as you are only interested in the `tagName` property, which exists on `Element` I would just change your code to use `Element`.

```js
const labelEl: HTMLElement = document.createElement('label')
const isElOfNeededType = (el: Element): boolean =>
    ["INPUT", "TEXTAREA"].includes(el.tagName);

let result

if (isElOfNeededType(labelEl.nextElementSibling)) {
    result = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue, even though the context was different.

As previously [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58363373/3032543) by @Colliere, the
problem is that `.nextElementSibling` is returning an `Element`, while we often need it as an `HTMLElement`.

A straightforward solution is change the type to HTMLElement before using it.

In your example you can use [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) like this:

```
const labelEl: HTMLElement = document.createElement('label')
const isElOfNeededType = (el: HTMLElement): boolean =>
    ["INPUT", "TEXTAREA"].includes(el.tagName);

let result

if (isElOfNeededType(labelEl.nextElementSibling as HTMLElement)) {
    result = true
}
```

I used JSDOC, so I had to use JSDOC [type casting](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25028#issuecomment-397875427) (note the extra parentheses):

```js
    const nextElementSibling = (
        /** @type {HTMLElement} */
        (labelEl.previousElementSibling)
    );
```